# Could not start a new session using Selenium RemoteWebDriver for SauceLabs

Tags: saucelabs, remotewebdriver

Following Code for **SauceLabs through Selenium** was working properly but now giving error:

```
static WebDriver driver;
public static final String URL = "http://" + USERNAME + ":" + ACCESS_KEY + "@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub";

        @BeforeClass
        public static void setupTest() throws MalformedURLException {
            DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
            caps.setCapability("platform", Platform.MAC);
            caps.setCapability("version", "52");
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(URL), caps);
        }
```

Error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
```

I have checked for both Chrome and Firefox. Can anyone please suggest if I am missing anything here. As the code was working properly before, can it be proxy issue?

Comment: Did you change anything before it stopped working?

Comment: Not changed anything in code.

Answer (score 0):

There were additional spaces.
Try `public static final String URL = "http"+USERNAME+":"+ACCESS_KEY+"@oandemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub";`